Why aren't my Flutter variables initialied on startup
I'm facing a peculiar issue with my Flutter app. When running the release APK, the variables on my home page aren't initialized correctly on startup. However, if I navigate to another page and then return to the home page, everything is fine. This behavior doesn't occur in debug mode.
I've also noticed that the splash screen in the release APK appears for a very brief moment, almost like a flash. I suspect this might be related to the initialization issue.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem before?

Since release mode is faster than debug mode it could be a timing issue that you haven't considered. You need to post a specific problem with MRE so that it can be answered/investigated properly.

Hi! Since it's happening in release mode what do you advice me to upload?

Well to start with it sounds like at least two possibly separate problems. Take one at a time. So in this case start with the variables. I suspect that the way you init the variables on your homepage isn't following some form of sound convention. So make sure to post code for an MRE for the variable init on the homepage

i updated the question with the code. i hope this is what you asked for cause im really desperate

In general I would not call any async function in initState. If you need values from async operations for your widget build consider using a FutureBuilder. Since checkAndLoadData is async the first build (especially in release mode) will run earlier than the async functions are completed.

@PeterKoltai I updated the code as shown above but the problem still exists. Did i do it wrong?

I don't see a FutureBuilder. Check out FutureBuilder in the documentation. Basically checkAndLoadData() (and other async functions needed to build your widget) should be inside a FutureBuilder.

@PeterKoltai i did what you said and now sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't (so that's something) did i do something wrong?

It's hard to tell, I don't see you current code. Maybe you should simplify your issue because as the code is current in the question it is not reproducible by me or someone else.

@PeterKoltai making a splash screen and then redircting to the app solved the problem. Thank's a lot though for making me understand the problem better

Making a splash screen and then redircting to the app solved the problem. Also  the comments of @PeterKoltai under the question are really useful
